# Array not returned properly(Titanium)

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, arrays, titanium

I am returning the array using a function in titanium.There are two entries in my array which are showing alert but when i access the returned value in another js file.It only show one value in alert
Here is my code (it is in db.js):

```
function quizfun() {
    var dataArray=new Array();
    var quizes = db.execute('select * from Quiz');
    while (quizes.isValidRow()) {
        var counter = 0;
        dataArray[counter] = quizes.fieldByName('Quiz_Text');
        quizes.next();
        alert(dataArray[counter]);//Showing two values
        counter++;
    };
    return dataArray;
}
```

Here is my other js file:

```
  quizes = db.quizfun();
  alert(quizes[0]);//working
  alert(quizes[1]);//alert not showing anything
```

Could you tell me what i am doing wrong.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var counter = 0;` should be outside the while loop. Like

```
function quizfun() {
    var dataArray=new Array();
    var quizes = db.execute('select * from Quiz');
    var counter = 0;
    while (quizes.isValidRow()) {
        dataArray[counter] = quizes.fieldByName('Quiz_Text');
        quizes.next();
        alert(dataArray[counter]);//Showing two values
        counter++;
    };
    return dataArray;
}
```

Comment: perfect answer just give me the reason so that i could avoid next time

Comment: Alternatively you can get rid of counter, and take advantage of Array's "push" method: dataArray.push(quizes.fieldByName('Quiz_Test'));